# How can I pass optional URL parameters through my rewrite rule?

Tags: php, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created a CMS that identifies if the GET value of `url` is defined, and if it is, it returns the html contents of the page from the frontend template on `index.php`. This ideally is to make a templating system that people who don't know much PHP can use, while being able to expand on it if they ever do know PHP.

It all worked fine with this htaccess. The following htaccess converts `http://localhost/index.php?url=(page)` to `http://localhost/(page)`.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(|/)$ index.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=$1
```

However, I expanded the CMS to identify if the GET url `end` is set. If it's value is backend, and the value of `$_GET['url']` isn't defined, it assumes that the value is index. If the value is defined, it uses the value to fetch that file. I now want my htaccess to do the following:

1. If the first parameter is `backend` then make the url from `http://localhost/index.php?end=backend&url=manage-pages` to `http://localhost/backend/manage-pages`.
2. If it is anything but `backend` convert it from `http://localhost/index.php?url=(page)` to `http://localhost/(page)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [QSA flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) on your rewrite rule.  It preserves any query string from the original URL and appends it to the new URL.  Your rewrite rule would be:

```
RewriteRule ^(|/)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```